# What's mass assignment in Rails and does it need a special name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I don't know if the term "mass assignment" is Rails-specific but I get the basic idea that mass assignment is when you assign values to a bunch of variables all in the same method.

Is that a correct definition and why is there a special name for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mass assignment in Rails is when you use something like `User.new(:name => "David", :occupation => "Code Artist")` to set all of the values for a row at once.  The danger comes in when you change this code to be more like `User.new(params[:user])`.  Now it's possible for an end user to maliciously craft the Hash that is passed in as a parameter to `User.new` and set variables you weren't expecting.  Hence the need for `attr_accessible` and `attr_protected`, which limit an end user's ability to set fields that they shouldn't be able to affect directly.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, without mass assignment, you would create a model like this:

```
user = User.new
user.first_name = params[:user][:first_name]
user.last_name = params[:user][:last_name]
```

With mass assignment the model itself will figure out to call those setters and all you need to do is

```
user = User.new(params[:user])
```

So yes, it is - kind of - setting a lot of variables with one method.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the default behavior of ActiveRecord is prone to vulnerability.  Specifically, updating attributes automatically from user submitted forms [mass updating can expose vulnerabilities](http://railspikes.com/2008/9/22/is-your-rails-application-safe-from-mass-assignment).  My guess is that the term mass updating has been popularized as a handle to discuss both the conveniences and vulnerabilities of this ActiveRecord feature.